# What does "npm:" prefix in dependency section in package.json mean?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am wondering what does that mean:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mui/styled-engine": "npm:@mui/styled-engine-sc@5.3.0",
}
```

What is that `npm:` prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/npm/cli/commit/b7b54f2d18e2d8d65ec67c850b21ae9f01c60e7e

this commit introduced aliasing to npm cli

Answer (score 1):

Probably telling npm where to get the package from (in this case npm):
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies

There's also `file:` and `git:` as you can see.

Comment: ok, but what does this "from npm" even mean? Elaborate.

Comment: So if you scroll down a little from where I linked, you'll eventually see Git URLs and Local paths. `file:` is install from local path, and `git`:` is install from Git repository. It's telling npm where to get the package from instead of the default npm registry. I think here it has no use because it's saying get the package from npm.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this code for many times:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "npm:sass@x.y.z",
}
```

It makes npm download sass instead of node-sass.